# apache2 python cgi misconfiguration

Tags: permissions, apache2, cgi, suexec

I am having problems with executing a python script from a browser.
My script is simple as follows,

cameron_toll.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
import mapnik
print "Done"
```

The permissions are as follows,

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data    77 2011-11-28 12:59 cameron_toll.py
drwxrwsr-x 2 antony antony 4096 2011-11-28 10:42 cgi-bin
```

I have also tried setting "antony antony" to the cameron_toll.py but still does not work. 
My error log file is,

```
[Mon Nov 28 14:36:43 2011] [error] [client 92.27.17.145] suexec policy violation:     see   suexec log for more details
[Mon Nov 28 14:36:43 2011] [error] [client 92.27.17.145] Premature end of script headers: cameron_toll.py
```

the script runs fine from my shell window which means that python is ok and mapnik is imported fine.

Any ideas or suggestions would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: may I add the following suexec logs,

[2011-11-28 15:26:49]: uid: (1001/antony) gid: (1005/antony) cmd: cameron_toll.py
[2011-11-28 15:26:49]: target uid/gid (1001/1005) mismatch with directory (1001/1005) or program (1001/33)

Comment: Ok, I think I have got it.
It was a permission error indeed. I had a user misconfiguration. The User did not have rights to execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I have got it. It was a permission error indeed. I had a user misconfiguration. The User did not have rights to execute..

Comment: Congrats on the solution.  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others might learn from your success.  Cheers~